# Set limit in add compare product in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to set limits to add compare products in  Magento 2.3.3.
Any user only adds 3 products in the compare list.
Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [magento 2 - Set limit to the compared product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159534/magento-2-set-limit-to-the-compared-product)

Comment: I have checked this. It is not working in Magento 2.3.3. @Rakesh Donga