# Magento 2.3 - Set max compare products to 3

Tags: magento2.3, compare

I want to limit the max products to compare to 3.
I tried to create this module: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159543/16894

But it seems that this does not work with Magento 2.3, because I do not get any message and still can add more than 3 items.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: limiting is one thing, but reading your post, I do not know how you want the limit to be enforced? is there an error message appearing when user attempts to add 4 products to the comparator or is it another usability that I might not see obvious

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy Thanks for the reply! Yes, it should display a error message, that there can only be 3 items displayed. This part is already in the module, `if($count > self::LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            'You can add the compared products under 3 item(s)'
        );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tuned the answer that you did find faulty. The change is minor but hopefully it resolve your issue.

```
public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        $count = $this->helper->getItemCount();
        if ($count >= self::$LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                sprintf('Only up to %s items can be added to the comparison list', self::$LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS)
            );

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Herve I used this method but the message gets displayed on another page or on refresh

Comment: Would love to help but have struggled with time lately. Will try to help again soon, thanks for your understanding

Comment: @arjun your issue is likely due to the setup of your compare product feature in your site. This feature can be setup in various fashion. I suggest you may add a new question and describe what is your setup so that I can replicate your issue easily